# Question about existence of partial derivatives at a point

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, vectors, partial-derivative

When a function has a problem at a certain point (for example point $(0,0)$ makes the denominator go to zero-I will use this here) and we define it at that point in cases where doing this makes the function continuous, then how to obtain the partial derivatives of the function at that point?

I know that we can do that with the definition of the partial derivatives. But, can't we just find the derivatives of the function for non-problematic points and then take the limit $(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)$?

I did this is some exercises I found and while I got particular answers using the definition, when I did the second method I found that the limit depended on the parameter m when I put $y=mx$ to find if the limit exists. So, I am mistaken, but I don't know where and why.

EDIT: So, now I know that those two things are not the same. I understand it, formally. But, conceptually I do not understand their difference.

**Example**(from the comments): For example, the function $f=0$ when $(x,y)=(0,0)$ and $f=(xy^2-x^2y+3x^3-y^3)/(x^2+y^2)$ otherwise. Using the definition of partial derivatives, I find that the two partials are zero at $(0,0)$. But if I compute the functions of the partials and then take their limit as $(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)$ and put y=mx I find that each limit depends on the value of m; which means that the limits do not exist. And my problem is why are these two ways not equivalent? What's conceptually(or informally) different about them? Why don't I get the same result?

Comment: Derivatives are not necessarily continuous.  Taking limits may give you a value, but it might not actually be the derivative.  Even in the one dimensional case, $x^2 \sin(1/x^2)$ has derivative $0$ at $x=0$ but you can't see this by taking limits of the derivative away from $0$

Comment: @ErickWong But, in order for the partial to exist at the origin, shouldn't the limit exist and give the same value for every value of the parameter m?

Comment: Yes, that is a necessary condition, but you are talking about two conceptually very different limits.  The derivative is itself a limit, so when you say find the derivative away from $(0,0)$ and take the limit of that, you're talking about a limit of limits.  Not the same thing.

Comment: @ErickWong Ok, but even if I am taking the limit of the limit, what is conceptually different? I mean, when I find the derivative away from the origin(as a function) I can treat it as any other function by taking limit as (x,y)->(0,0) to find if that limit exists, right? I mean, what's conceptually different about this?

Comment: This is the problem with thinking in vague, imprecise notions.  Just because you're taking a limit in both cases does not make them necessarily the same thing.  The limits that you're taking are conceptually not the same because they simply have different definitions; the onus is on you to justify that you can exchange one for the other.

Comment: @ErickWong Okay, then the question is now about what the difference between the two is. It's been like this from the beginning I think

Answer (score 1):

"But, can't we just find the derivatives of the function for non-problematic points and then take the limit (x,y)->(0,0)?". Yes you can. Suppose $f$ is continuous at $(0,0),$ $f_x,f_y$ exist in a deleted neighborhood of $(0,0),$ and

$$\tag 1\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} f_x(x,y) = a, \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} f_y(x,y) = b,$$

where $a,b \in \mathbb R.$ Then $f_x(0,0)=a, f_y(0,0)=b.$ (And in fact $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$ with $Df(0,0)(x,y) = ax + by.$) That's a nice little mean value theorem exercise.

But, Warnings: 1) You can't find limits as in $(1)$ by just looking along certain paths. 2) Just because the limits in $(1)$ fail to exist does not imply $f_x(0,0), f_y(0,0)$ fail to exist, nor does it imply $Df(0,0)$ fails to exist.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although the real question is why I can't do your two last points! This is what I am doing in my exercises and get different results from that given when I calculate the derivatives from the definition. If you could edit the answer to include these point, I would really appreciate it

Comment: You should give a specific example

Comment: For example, the function f=0 when (x,y)=(0,0) and f=(x*y^2-x^2*y+3x^3-y^3)/(x^2+y^2) otherwise. Using the definition of partial derivatives, I find that the two partials are zero at (0,0). But if I compute the functions of the partials and then take their limit as (x,y)-->(0,0) and put y=mx I find that each limit depends on the value of m; which means that the limits do not exist. And my problem is why are these two ways not equivalent? What's conceptually(or informally) different about them? Why don't I get the same result?

Comment: I get $f_x(0,0) = 3,f_y(0,0) = -3.$

Comment: Me, and the official solution, gives 3 and -1 respectively. But, it;s not the values that matter but that we don't obtain the same results using the second method(limit of the function of the partial derivative rather than the definition of the partial dervative)

Comment: Sorry, I thought there was a 3 in front of the y^3. But the main answer is you have a fundamental misunderstanding: $A \implies B$ is not the same as $B\implies A.$

Comment: Yeah, I kind of understood this but what I do not understand is what is the difference between the two ways. For what does the number that I find through the definition stand for and what does the number I find by taking the limit of the function of the derivative stand for?

Answer (score 1):

zhw's answer shows that what you propose is fine provided that the function is sufficiently continuous and well-behaved (note that a function may be wildly discontinuous at $(0,0)$ and still have both partial derivatives exist at $(0,0)$).  But this is a theorem, it's something that must be justified (and it can be, given the specified regularity assumptions).

Let's break down what you're saying into formal definitions.  The partial derivative $f_x(0,0)$ is *defined* by the limit:

$$f_x(0,0) = \lim_{y\to 0} \frac{f(0,y) - f(0,0)}{y}.$$

The limit you are asking about in your question is the *limit* of the partial derivative at values away from $(0,0)$.  Specifically:

$$\lim_{(x_0,y_0)\to(0,0)} f_x(x_0,y_0) = \lim_{(x_0,y_0)\to(0,0)} \lim_{y\to y_0} \frac{f(x_0,y) - f(x_0,y_0)}{y-y_0}.$$

There is no intrinsic reason to believe these are the same for arbitrary functions: you can't assume that limits within limits pass through without further conditions on the function $f$.

In the comments I mentioned that the one-variable function $g(x) = x^2 \sin(1/x^2)$ satisfies $g'(0) = 0$ but $\lim_{x\to 0} g'(x)$ does not exist.  So the function $f(x,y) = g(x)$ would have the same problem.  But there are simpler examples that I alluded to earlier: take any function where $f(x,y) = 0$ whenever $xy=0$, but where $f(x,y)$ takes arbitrary values for $x\ne0$ and $y\ne 0$.  Then $f_x(0,0) = f_y(0,0) = 0$, but $f_x(x_0,y_0)$ may very well not exist for any $y_0\ne 0$, let alone the limit of $f_x(x_0,y_0)$.

Comment: Ok, so formally I understand why they are not the same. But, conceptually, why are they different things? Why can't I take the limit of a partial derivative at the origin and have the same result as I would take if I calculated it with the definition? It's the intuition that I don't get.

Comment: @TheQuantumMan Intuitively, the limit you're asking about is "can I measure the slope at the peak of a mountain by measuring all the slopes of the points nearby (except for the peak itself)?"  And one answer is "maybe not, if the peak is sufficiently weird-looking.

Comment: Is it something like trying to find the derivative of the following graph at x=-4 and x=2? https://www.google.com.cy/search?q=discontinuous+function+examples&espv=2&biw=1366&bih=667&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiwneTphdbOAhWKvRoKHYpVCAMQ_AUIBigB#imgrc=E20BosPCJJn0lM%3A

Comment: Because, we can compute its derivative at x=-4 and x=2 but if I try to find it using the limit(not the definition) then the situation would get messy

Comment: @TheQuantumMan That actually raises a good point I forgot to mention: it's also possible for a derivative to have a limit at $0$ even though the function is discontinuous (hence non-differentiable) there, for instance $f(x) = x+1$ when $x\ge 0$ and $f(x) = x$ when $x<0$.

Comment: So, my example was right?

Comment: @TheQuantumMan I'm not sure what you mean by "right".  It's an analogy — it's not really something that's right or wrong, just shades of analogousness.

Comment: In your first comment(of this answer) you said "can I measure the slope at the peak of a mountain by measuring all the slopes of the points nearby (except for the peak itself)?". Isn't the example in the link I provided a good analogy of this to a single-variable case?

Comment: I mean, if I try to find the value of the derivative at x=2 with the definition I will get a certain value while if I do it the second way(which you say is not always correct) I end up trying to find the slope at x=2 based on the slopes of nearby points, which is wrong. Isn't this what you were trying to say?

Comment: @TheQuantumMan Sure, that's pretty much what I was trying to say.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot